# Source code definition or explanation for numpy zlapack_lite.c

Tags: python, numpy

Does anyone know of a knowledge resource to understand the code structure of the core numpy algorithms? I am trying to understand the implmentation of SVD in numpy and it is difficult to comprehend how the function array indirection is done from py files eg: numpy.linalg.linalg.py to the lapack C files is done and also the code inside C files is long. I can painstakingly try to understand but thought if there is a good code documentation for the lapack implementations.